# Network settings only allows me to add pptp vpns

Tags: network-manager, 16.10, openvpn

I'm trying to add an openvpn to my network connections but when I try to add a vpn it will only allow me to add a PPTP connection.

Running `sudo openvpn --config file.ovpn` works but then I don't have the connection in the network menu on the top.

How can I add openvpn connections to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run following command in Terminal to install the OpenVPN network manager.

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

Comment: Thanks, This worked. I can't understand why this doesn't come installed by default..